# hide and show a table column

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I need to hide the last column which is checkboxes based on the model Object passed from spring controller. If the model value is "isAll" column should be hidden if any other value it should be visible I have tried but so far failed.  Im not sure if Im passing the value from the controller correctly.  HELP!

Controller:

```
    System.err.println("Type is: " + formbean.getType());
System.err.println("IscCode is: " + formbean.getForecastIsc());
System.err.println("ActualIscCode is: " + formbean.getActualIsc());
System.err.println("labelNbr is: " + formbean.getLabelNbr());
System.err.println("senderOp is: " + formbean.getSenderOp());       
System.err.println("senderLastName is: " + formbean.getSenderLastName());
System.err.println("receiverOp is: " + formbean.getReceiverOp());
System.err.println("receiverLastName is: " + formbean.getReceiverLastName());


    summary = summarySelectDao.getSummary(formbean);    
    if(summary == null || summary.size() == 0){         
        errorMessage = "No Parcel Analysis Cases Found!";
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/analysis/analysisSelection? hasError=true");
    }else{
    logger.info("Total " + summary.size() + " analysis cases found from DB.");
        model.addObject("summary", summary);
        model.addObject("isAll", true);  //BASED on this model if true
    }

    return model;
```

JSP:

```
<td class="ct"<c:out value="${summary.country}" /></td>
 <td class="sc" <c:out value="${summary.source}" /></td>
 <td  class="cb" <input type="checkbox" value=""> </td>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".cb").hide();    
});
```

HTML:

```
   <div id=table1>
<table id="summaryTable" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Bar Code</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Sender Name</th>
            <th>Recipient Name</th>
            <th>USPS Mail<br>Receipt Date</th>
            <th><br>Load Date</th>
            <th>Fore-<br>cast<br> ISC</th>
            <th>Act-<br>ual<br> ISC</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Source</th>
<th class="cb"><input type="button" id="btnSelectAllCbl" name="selectCheckBox"
            value="Update"> </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr>

                <tr>
<td bgcolor='yellow'>P
    </td>
    <td bgcolor='yellow'><a href="AnalysisController?value=xxxxx">xxxxx
    </a>
    </td>
    <td bgcolor='yellow'>55025
                    </td>
    <td bgcolor='yellow'>xxxx
                    </td>
    <td bgcolor='yellow'>SON
    </td>
 <td  bgcolor='yellow'>
        </td>
<td bgcolor='yellow'>2013/02/11 060205
</td>
<td bgcolor='yellow'>ORD
                    </td>
<td bgcolor='yellow'>ORD
                    </td>
                    <td  bgcolor='yellow'>SINGAPORE
                    </td>
                    <td  bgcolor='yellow'>RECIPIENT
                    </td>
                    <td class="cb" bgcolor='yellow'><input
                        type="checkbox" value="">
                    </td>
```

Comment: are you not displaying HTML at all, or just not hiding the last column?  I think the HTML in your JSP is invalid, if you're trying to display values in cells.  You need to close the TD tags before the <c:out... tag.

Comment: It should work when <td> is correctly closed, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/D2LR3/

Comment: Sorry may be I confused you a bit.  hide function is working fine but What I need is that it only hides the column when the value passed from the controller is 'isAll"  otherwise it should display the column.  Right now its hiding the column even if  "isAll" is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way: use `<c:if>` in order to print/not print the column at all:

```
<c:if test="${isAll}">
    <td  class="cb"><input type="checkbox" value=""></td>
</c:if>
```

Do the same for the column header as well.

Comment: Thanks! @Luiggi Mendoza So by using <c:if> I still need to use jquery? If yes can you elaborate on how would I code that part..

Comment: No, just remove the jquery part.